# How to ecape the "." character in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a MVC view where I need to render something like this:

```
<img src="foo/@(Model.Id).jpg" />
```

The problem is that Razor thinks the dot in ".jpg" belongs to the previous statement and thus tells me that there are no such field or property called "jpg". How can I overcome this?

Comment: Are you sure? Because locally with MVC4 such line - `foo/@(Model.Id).jpg` renders such html `foo/51.jpg`. 51 is value of Model.Id that I set before

Comment: Must be my mistake, cause previously I have this statement enclosed in another @if block. Works now, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine for me and display correct html with ID in it `foo/51.jpg`. 51 is number from my model.

But just as another idea you can save it as local variable like this:

```
@{
    string path = "foo/" + Model.Id + ".jpg";
}
<img src="@path" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this version, this would probably work

**Edited:**

```
<img src=@("foo/" + Model.Id  + ".jpg") /> <!-- Try this simplified version -->
```

Comment: No it does not, because the rendered html will be <img src="/foo/123" + ".jpg" />, and obviously the browser does not understand this.

Comment: What about the Edited answer. seems like you found the answer, but give it a try this much simplified version